# How can I do this but using StringBulider

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I am trying to replicate this code using `StringBuilder` but can't figure out how.

What this does is check a given string (`tweetText`) with an array of Strings (`usernames`) and if is a match replaces the one in the string adding an "@" before it.

For example:

If the string was; **It seems like DonaldTrump and JoeBiden will both run for president in 2024.**

and in the array of usernames were **{"DonaldTrump", "JoeBiden"}**

the result should be: **It seems like @DonaldTrump and @JoeBiden will both run for president in 2024.**

This is my code that works without the use of `StringBuilder`:

```java
public String highlightUsernames(String tweetText, String[] usernames) {
    String  resultText = "" ;

    for (int i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
        tweetText = tweetText.replace(usernames[i], "@"+usernames[i]);
    }

    return tweetText;
}
```

I'm not understanding very well how `StringBuilder` works...

Comment: "I´m not understanding very well how StrinBuilder works..." then why do you want to use it? Have you considered it may not be the right tool for the job?

Comment: Tweets are designed to be short, so there is usually no need for these kind of tricks. Copying a small tweet message is not a huge job for a computer. This post will have consumed more CPU & memory.

Comment: By the way, there are all kinds of interesting issues, but the compare should at the very least respect word boundaries. Currently it also matches the last part of nick `"NotJoeBiden"`...

Answer (score 2):

Your actual approach is the way to go.  I would forget about using `StringBuilder` for this.  But here is a related suggestion.
If you want to ensure that existing strings in the array are not already prefixed with an @ sign, then do it as follows using [String.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)).  This also enforces word boundaries so if any names are part of an existing word (e.g. `Same vs Sam`) it won't be changed.

```
String[] names = {"DonaldTrump", "JoeBiden"};
    
String s = "It seems like DonaldTrump and JoeBiden will both run for president in 2024.";
```

- `(?<!@)` - Is a negative look-behind assertion which says `@` does not occur before name.
- `\\b` - enforces word boundaries.  Suggested by [Maarten Bodewes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589259/maarten-bodewes)

```
for (String name : names) {
        s = s.replaceAll("\\b(?<!@)"+name+"\\b", "@"+name);
}
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Yes, thank you.THe thing is they are asking me to use StringBuilder...

Comment: Well, that's important information that wasn't stated as a requirement in your question.

Comment: Sorry I did not include that info

Answer (score 2):

Using StringBuilder will give a better performance in this case. here's a simple implementation:

```
public String highlightUsernames(String tweetText, String[] usernames) {

    StringBuilder  resultText = new StringBuilder(tweetText) ;

    for (int i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
        var index = 0;
        while (true) {
            index = resultText.indexOf(usernames[i], index);
            if (index == -1)
                break;
            resultText.insert(index, "@");
            index +=2;
        }
    }
    return resultText.toString();
}
```

Comment: `do { ... } while (index != -1);` instead of a `while(true)` with a `break` would probably be more clear.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I'd simply start with `index = 0` though, and do away with the `+ 2`. Instead you can do `+ 1` after insertion. Currently you start with index `1` which is not correct, Donald may come first again, god forbid. Currently it is not just less clear, it's slightly incorrect.

Comment: Oh, yeah, +2, good catch :) I really should not do anything serious at the moment, I'm all over the place.

Comment: Thank you all so much. I am amazed of how quick my question was solved!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Let's dive deep into this and make something really performant. It uses the smarts of regular expressions to find all names at once, and then inserts the @ symbol if there isn't one already. It stores the indexes, so that any string copying only has to be performed once (or twice when you call `StringBuilder#toString()` of course).

It also fixes a major issue with your code: that it matches `"JoeBiden"` in `"JoeBidenAgain"` by using *word boundaries*. Actually, a Java/regex "word" character nicely coincides with the rules for Twitter names / handles (probably that's not coincidental).

```
String[] names = {"DonaldTrump", "JoeBiden"};

String namesForRegexp = Arrays.stream(names).map(s -> Pattern.quote(s)).collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(?<!@)(" + namesForRegexp + ")\\b");

String s = "It seems like DonaldTrump and JoeBidenAgain will both run for president in 2024.";

Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
List<Integer> insertionPoints = new LinkedList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    // do our own lookbehind for existing @ sign
    insertionPoints.add(m.start());
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length() + insertionPoints.size());
int offset = 0;
for (int insertionPoint : insertionPoints) {
    sb.append(s.substring(offset, insertionPoint));
    sb.append('@');
    offset = insertionPoint;
}
sb.append(s.substring(offset));

System.out.println(sb);
```

This will print out:

```
It seems like @DonaldTrump and JoeBidenAgain will both run for president in 2024.
```

Note that `"JoeBidenAgain"` is now not tagged with a `@` sign, that's probably somebody else after all.

---

**Tweets are deliberately small**, so this kind of unnecessary optimization would not make much sense for an actual tweet; it should be more of an illustration on how to generally optimize such a function.

Comment: Inserting into a `StringBuilder` (repeatedly), shifting the characters behind the insertion position, is *less* efficient than `String result = p.matcher("It seems like DonaldTrump and JoeBiden will both run for president in 2024.") .replaceAll("@$0");` Of course, the `Matcher`’s `replaceAll` will also use a `StringBuilder` behind the scenes, but copy the fragments between matches in time, without the need to shift subsequent characters. And it’s smart enough to return the original string when there’s no match, so it doesn’t copy the contents into a `StringBuilder` in that case.

Comment: Good point. I guess you can optimize that away as well by performing the inserts afterwards. I've really only optimized the search.

Comment: @Holger There, fixed it. Single search run, no unnecessary copies.

Comment: This is a classical case where `ArrayList` performs better than `LinkedList` but you don’t need this list anyway. You do the operation in a single loop. And avoid the overhead of `substring` by using `sb.append(s, offset, insertionPoint);` instead of `sb.append(s.substring(offset, insertionPoint));` Likewise replace the last `sb.append(s.substring(offset));` by `sb.append(s, offset, s.length());` And, as said, if no match is found, the result can be the original string.

Comment: Putting it all together, `CharSequence result; Matcher m = p.matcher(s); if(!m.find()) result = s; else { StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length() + 16); int offset = 0; do sb.append(s, offset, offset = m.start()).append('@'); while(m.find()); result = sb.append(s, offset, s.length()); }` This has the small risk that the `StringBuilder`’s capacity is not sufficient, but even if this happens, the overhead is not worse than maintaining a `List` of boxed `Integer` objects in the first place.

Comment: It’s also worth knowing [the implementation of `replaceAll`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/regex/Matcher.java#L1197) for comparison… [`appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuilder,java.lang.String)) and [`appendTail`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail(java.lang.StringBuilder)) are public methods which can be used as building blocks for custom replacement operations.

Answer (score -2):

The purpose of the StringBuilder class is to create a mutable sequence of characters, since the String class is immutable.

I don't think in your case is necessary since you can use something like this:

```
    for( String username: usernames ) {
            s = s.replace(username, "@" + username);

   }
```

But assuming the purpose is to understand how StringBuilder works, here is an updated function that uses the StringBuilder class:

```
        public String highlightUsernames(String tweetText, String[] usernames) {
         // You can create an instance of the StringBuilder class with the tweetText String.
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(tweetText);
        
            for (int i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
                
                // Get the index of the user
               int index = stringBuilder.indexOf(usernames[i]);
               
               // And use the insert method of StringBuilder to add the "@" before the username if it's found
               if (index != -1) {
                    stringBuilder.insert(index, "@");
                }
            }
            
            // At the end, you can convert the StringBuilder to a String, using its toString method
            return stringBuilder.toString();
```